How would you say "There's no going back." in Latin?
One of the listened-to song in Croatia these days is "Rim Tim Tagi Dim", and its reffrain is "There's no going back.". How would you say that in Latin? My attempt would be "Non est via retro.", but I'm almost sure that's incorrect.

With the category of idioms, would it be better to use the phrase recorded for Caesar crossing the Rubicon?   The die is cast.  "alea iacta est"  for example https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17852/a-latin-phrase-for-a-thing-which-has-been-done-cannot-be-changed/17853#17853  and / or https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/alea-iacta-est-plural-version
